# How do I automatically select an include.h file based on compiler directive -D?

Tags: c++, include, header-files, preprocessor, compiler-flags

I would like to have a general include.h header file in my program that will list all possible include files to be used when selected using a -D ITEM=ITEM1 compiler flag.
If I want to build this library for example for ITEM1, then -D ITEM=ITEM1 for item2, it will be -D ITEM=ITEM2.

header.h file:

```
#ifdef ITEM1
#include item1.h
#endif
#ifdef ITEM2
#include item2.h
#endif
```

the header files item1.h and item2.h will be a **symbolic link** from another directory outside of the working directory.

When I do this scheme, I get scope errors on the defines inside each of item1.h or item2.h

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `-D ITEM1` or `-D ITEM2` for your posted code to work. If you want to base your logic of `-D ITEM=...`, you'll need to use `-D ITEM=1` or `-D ITEM=2` and change your code to:

```
#ifdef ITEM

#if ITEM == 1
#include item1.h
#elif ITEM == 2
#include item2.h
#else
// Unknown value of ITEM. Figure out what do for this case.
#endif

#else
// ITEM is not defined. Figure out what do for this case.
#endif
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this... this is what I was looking for to implement.

Comment: @SydPao, you're welcome. Glad I was able to help. Happy programming.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `-D` incorrectly.  When you do

```
-D ITEM=ITEM1
```

you define the `ITEM` symbol and give it the value `ITEM1`.  This not what you want as it leave `ITEM1` and `ITEM2` undefined so neither file is included.  What you need is

```
-D ITEM1
//or
-D ITEM2
```

to define either of those symbols.